# Вопрос по таблице

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Есть часть таблицы

Из такого
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должна перейти на такое(в мобильной версии)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, можно ли добиться успеха, если использовать для этого table?

```
    <section class="timetable-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="p-hours-start">09:56</p>
                                    <p class="p-hours-end">11:02</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn-new-group">
                                        <img src="img/ic_new_group.png" alt="">
                                        <span class="color-gray-c">GROUPE</span>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p>2J <span class="color-gray-c">22H</span> <span class="color-gray-l">32M</span></p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="p-cost-sncf"><strike>56,90</strike></p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="p-text-ttc">a partir de</p>
                                    <p class="p-cost-ttc">32,45 <span class="currency">€</span></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Или все-таки использовать для этого Bootstrap-сетку? И Если использовать сетку, то как расположить ячейки в указанном порядке?

Answer (score 1):

В бутстрапе есть мощный инструмент push-pull, позволяющий переставлять местами ячейки. Можете использовать его:

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3">12:43 - 15:38</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-push-5"><s>48,90E</s></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-2"><b>3</b>/10</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-2">2J 22H 32M</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">24,90</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а если использовать bootstrap 4? там же push/pull убрали.

Comment: @VulgarShepard, с 4-м пока не доводилось иметь дел, ничего не могу сказать (слышал, что он на флексах - это принципиально иная технология, нежели флоаты)